# Why forcing docker to remove all container always give exit status 125

Tags: docker, go

I'm writing this naive code in golang to ask docker to remove all container by force, but when running it, it always give me err: `exit status 125`.

I'm extremely confused as it runs smoothly on my own cli.

```
func removeAllContainers() error {
    // container ls -a -q | xargs docker container rm
    _, err := exec.Command(
        "docker",
        "container",
        "ls",
        "-a",
        "-q",
        "|",
        "xargs",
        "docker",
        "container",
        "rm",
        "-f",
    ).Output()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("cannot remove all containers: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

This error message is very uninformative -- we only know that the deamon is having some problem, but don't know what that problem is! I wonder if there's a way to get more detailed error message when running a docker command in golang.

Comment: Pipe operation `|` is managed by the shell. You are passing it as an argument to docker. Run the command via shell.

Comment: `I wonder if there's a way to get more detailed error message` There is, print stderr.

Comment: @tkausl thanks! Could you elaborate on how to print stderr in golang?

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks! do you mean by adding `"sh"` to the beginning of this `exec.Command`?

Comment: Yes.  try `sh -c <docker cmd>`Currently you are running one command, `docker` that also contains ` | xargs...` as part of the arguments.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Running with `_, err := exec.Command("sh", "docker", "container", "ls",...` gave me error response 126 now.

Comment: What happens if you get the list of containers in one call, then remove in a second call?

Comment: You run commands using `sh -c <cmd>`

Comment: @AJcodez that definitely works but it may look a bit tedious.

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks so much! `_, err := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "docker", "container", "ls",...` works perfectly!